# What is the Natural Lifespan of Transformers?

Tags: transformers

**How long do or *can* Transformers live (naturally)?**

I understand that information may be limited; especially since they are [seemingly] constantly warring among themselves, and Earth's interaction with them has been very recent.

But say in a period of peace, how long could a Transformer live?

Please take into account their ability to heal (if they do), their hardiness (being extremely durable) and their technological advancements and capabilities.

*Canon answers only please.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No one knows. Not even the Transformers themselves.

In the IDW comics, a popular theory among Cybertronians is that they are indeed immortal. That they can only die through violent means. This theory, however, is challenged by many including the Autobot's Chief Medical Officer Ratchet. The disease known as Cybercrosis is often cited as a refutation to the idea of Cybertronian immortality and seems to be an analogy of dying of old age. The disease has no known cure, has a 100% fatality rate, and is caused by the spark inexplicably losing power. Ratchet theorizes that Cybercrosis results from old age and exposure to radiation. In the course of the comics we meet only one Cybertronian with the disease:

> Tailgate. Who was born just before Nova Prime left in the Ark I.

Making him around 6 million years old.

Comment: I see. So (almost) immortals; but they die of <strike>old age</strike> Cybercrosis.

Comment: @BorhanMooz - Yes. Very long lived, but definitely mortal.

Comment: Some other canon information would be good too... Like how Skydive stated in the Generation 2 comics how outside of warfare they are practically immortal.

Comment: So they experience no aging effects until they suddenly develop Cybercrosis, and then die shortly after? Because Jetfire looked pretty old in the movie, and he was falling apart it seemed like (literally as well as having to walk with a cane). Did he simply lack the regular maintenance/repairs that Transformers not in hibernation would have received? Or could he have just did the Bumblebee thing and instantly upgrade to a new model?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - The Michael Bay Transformers have their own continuity, which isn't that well explored. But in the IDW comics we have something similar happen to Kup. In one story he's been missing for a long time and when he's found his body was very decrepit. However, Perceptor was able to build him a new body and gave him a cigar (don't ask) and he's as good as new.

Comment: Bear in mind though - far, far older transformers than Tailgate have been met such as one who is over 20 million (Shockwave via timey wimey). Cybercrosis has also been cured as of the Tailgate arch and he had his kicked in in-part by radiation, not just naturally.